# AJAX form submisson

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, smarty

I'm coding a CMS for Game Server Sellers, but ran into a problem. I have the following code:

```
<div id="ServerResponse" align="center"></div>
<form id="RegistrationForm" method="post" action="/account.php?do=create">
  <input type='text' placeholder='{#Name#}' id='Name' name="Name" autocomplete="off">
  <input type='text' placeholder='{#Surname#}' id='Surname' name="Surname" autocomplete="off"><br />
  <select name="day" id="day" style='width: 55px;'>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>

  <select name="month" id="month" style='width: 90px;'>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
  </select>

  <select name="year" id="year" style='width: 70px;'>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
  </select>

  </br>

  <input type='text' placeholder='{#Username#}' id='Username' name="Username" autocomplete="off"><br />
  <input type='password' placeholder='{#Password#}' id='Password' name="Password" autocomplete="off"><br />
  <input type='password' placeholder='{#RPassword#}' id='RPassword' name="RPassword" autocomplete="off"><br />
  <input type='text' placeholder='EMail' id='Email' name="Email" autocomplete="off"><br />
  <input type='submit' value='{#Registration#}'> <input type="reset" value="{#ResetF#}"><br />
</form>

</center>
```

The thing is, I'm not able to make this form to post data through AJAX Post, it just opens `account.php?do=create` page.

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

All js like jquery.js, jquery.form.js are included

I'm using this code to do AJAX stuff:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var options = { 
      target: "#ServerResponse",
      timeout: 3000
    };

    $('#RegistrationForm').submit(function() { 
      $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
       return false;
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Also I'm using Smarty, and code mentioned above is inside `{literal}{/literal}` tags.

Comment: Errors in console? DOMReady?

Comment: No errors at all, yep, ready

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`  just after `$('#RegistrationForm').submit(function() {` maybe?

Comment: return false should prevent it action anywat, but thx for  reply, i'll try that now

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` as suggested in the comment above is ok, don't remember to specify `e` in the callback: `$('#RegistrationForm').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Submit` on a form is an `event` and to cancel the default action of a submit event you need to use `event.preventDefault();`. [See Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration)

> preventDefault
>
> If an event is cancelable, the preventDefault method is used to
>   signify that the event is to be canceled, meaning any default action
>   normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not
>   occur. If, during any stage of event flow, the preventDefault method
>   is called the event is canceled. Any default action associated with
>   the event will not occur. Calling this method for a non-cancelable
>   event has no effect. Once preventDefault has been called it will
>   remain in effect throughout the remainder of the event's propagation. This method may be used during any stage of event flow.

Maybe try your ajax this way.

```
$('#RegistrationForm').submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var postData = $(this).serialize();
 var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: formURL,
     timeout: 3000,
     data: postData,
     success: function(response){
       $("#ServerResponse").html(response);   
     }          
   });
});
```

Comment: Thx, but sinse im using smarty and html5, i just applied required tag to each form field, also created error page, looks great. Thx 4 your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your form element `onsubmit="return false"`

If that doesn't solve it, but instead it just does nothing, then make it `onsubmit="functionName();return false"`

Or do it adding an event handler to the form element, if you're particular about not using JavaScript attributes.

Comment: Tried that, still same thing, it just ignoring js, dunno why.

Comment: Try replacing the action value with # and see if that fixes it. Also, have you tried this in multiple browsers, and cleared your cache?

Comment: Tried that in IE10, Safari (latest), Chrome (latest), Firefox (latest) - gives the same result, just redirecting to mentioned page after Submit button is clicked. Browsers Cache is disabled, server-side cache disabled also

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but if nobody else can provide a solution, then I would think that doing `action="#"` would fix it, as the script would have time to run, and the actual submit button wouldn't do anything. Worth the try at least, even though it's a nasty fix.

Comment: @IvanZhivolupov Oh, also use Firefox and see if any JS errors are fired before the page changes. I've had that catch me before as well, and you never see them because the page refreshes. FF is the only one you can have keep them around. ([Ctrl] + [Shift] + J)

Comment: [FreedomCore Servers | Registration](http://games.freedomcore.eu/cp/registration) if you dont mind, can you please check this link? for me it's no error in both Chrome and Firefox